# Why is the "latest" release on GitHub different when pulling down the Docker image with the tag "latest"?

Tags: docker, github

I'm very new with working with Docker and GitHub, so if someone reads through this question and can re-word the title to make more technical sense, I'd appreciate it.

I'm trying to run a Docker instance of this GitHub project:
https://github.com/dani-garcia/bitwarden_rs

GitHub labels the "latest" release as 1.8.0:
https://github.com/dani-garcia/bitwarden_rs/releases

I did a "docker pull" for for 1.8.0, and for the one tagged "latest" and expected both to have the same image ID, they seem to be different (the hashes are different). Why is that the case?

```
C:\>docker images -a
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             
SIZE
mprasil/bitwarden          latest              439f568b0ca9        3 days ago          104MB
mprasil/bitwarden          1.8.0               532652c9b1c3        12 days ago         103MB
```

Answer (score 1):

You would really need to ask the image maintainers.

It is likely that `latest` is built from git `master`, while `1.8.0` is built from a specific release. Looking at the GitHub repository, `1.8.0` was released about 14 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

That's the difference

[image]

Normally, latest version in dockerhub means the latest stable version while lastet branch in GitHub means the develop branch.

But it depends on how the maintainer defines latest.